# Apache FELIX JAX-RS Change context path

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, apache-felix

I currently develop a REST Web service and expose it in bundle under FELIX. I'm using JAX-RS connector for the web service.
The service works fine but if I want to access to a resource the template URL is

http://IP:PORT/services/path/to/my/resource

The goal is to change the context path services to access to resource with URL 
like 
http://IP:PORT/path/to/my/resource

I tried to change the admin config as it has been described in the FAQ of JAX-RS connector but I still have problem

```
ServiceReference configurationAdminReference = bundleContext.getServiceReference(ConfigurationAdmin.class.getName());
if(configurationAdminReference != null) {
    ConfigurationAdmin confAdmin = (ConfigurationAdmin) bundleContext.getService(configurationAdminReference);
    if(confAdmin != null) {
        Configuration configConnector = confAdmin.getConfiguration("com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.connector",null); 
        Dictionary<String, String> props = configConnector.getProperties()
        if (props == null) {
            Dictionary<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String,String>();
         }
        props.put("root","/");    
        configConnector.update(props);
    }
}
```

I have seen that someone have already this problem in this forum but in my case it doesn't solve the problem
I can see in felix web console the following error message

Error: the PID "com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.connector" is bound to "file:/c:/Dev/Tools/Apache/Felix/bundle/mybundle-1.0.0.jar" but the actual managed service is registered from "inputstream:publisher-4.3.jar" bundle

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code results in a NullPointerException when `configConnector.getProperties()` returns null, as you're declaring a new variable `props` in the if-clause rather than assigning the new hashtable instance to the existing variable.

Once you fixed this you might run into this issue: https://github.com/hstaudacher/osgi-jax-rs-connector/issues/114

The following code works:

> ```
>     org.osgi.service.cm.Configuration configuration = configurationAdmin.getConfiguration("com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.connector", null);
>     Dictionary props = configuration.getProperties();
>     if (props == null) {
>         props = new Hashtable();
>     }
>     props.put("root", "/jaxrs");
>     configuration.update(props);
> ```